# CSS top, left block mouseover

Tags: jquery, css

Why when css `top` is defined jquery and html cant catch mouseover?
How to make it works?

```
<div id="myDiv" onmouseover="exe()" style="top: 10px;"></div>

<script>
    function exe(){
        alert();
    }
    $('#myDiv').mouseover(exe());
</script>
```

Comment: The trouble is probably that you don't have anything IN the div.  So there is nothing to rollover.

Comment: When i remove style it work's fine

Comment: Dropping that into a fiddle, I don't see that it works at all.  It runs the alert when it first runs and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Your div is empty, add a padding, then is a area for detection available.

```
<div id="myDiv" onmouseover="exe()" style="padding:5px"></div>
<script>
     function exe(){
         alert();
     }
     $('#myDiv').mouseover(exe());
</script>
```

[See JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wz0qgbzz/)